# BigQuery UI queries table, but AI notebook complains about permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have two projects. Project Apple has data in BQ tables. Project Banana has read access to Apple's BQ tables. When I run queries using Banana's BQ UI, everything is fine. The same query doesn't work in Banana's AI notebook.

Banana BQ UI:

```
  AVG(A) as A_mean_exact,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(A, 100)[OFFSET(50)] AS A_percentile_50_approx,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(A, 100)[OFFSET(90)] AS A_percentile_90_approx

FROM `apple.v1003.apple_table`
WHERE selected_run = 1
```

Works fine.

Banana's AI notebook:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client(location="US", project="banana") # I also tried apple; same error
print("Client creating using default project: {}".format(client.project))
```

`Client creating using default project: banana`

```
query = """
SELECT 
  AVG(A) as A_mean_exact,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(A, 100)[OFFSET(50)] AS A_percentile_50_approx,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(A, 100)[OFFSET(90)] AS A_percentile_90_approx

FROM `apple.v1003.apple_table`
WHERE selected_run = 1
"""
query_job = client.query(
    query,
    location="US",
) 

df = query_job.to_dataframe()
df
```

```
Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: Table apple:v1003.apple_table: User does not have permission to query table apple:v1003.apple_table.
```

Could you please suggest what I should look into? I am just starting with AI Hub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have currently given permissions to your project account, but the notebook is trying to access BigQuery through the service account associated to the Compute Engine instance that is running JupyterLab.

You have to go to Compute Egnine > your notebook machine > View network details > and see what service account is it using(in Banana). Then, give the permissions to that account in Apple's project IAM section.

Comment: I could swear that I posted a "thank you" comment here, but I can't see it. Anyway, yes, it worked! Thank you :) I can't upvote your answer because my reputation is too low.

Comment: Do you need more than just "view" permissions? I have read [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) that in order to export data from the BQ console for example you need "bigquery.tables.export" permission.